# Сервис или движок для создания заметок с кодом

Tags: task

Ищу сервис или движок для создания заметок с кодом. Возможно вики-движок. Нужна удобная навигация по группам/записям и простой функциональный редактор записей.
Сперва собирался написать свой сайт для этих целей, но потом подумал зачем изобретать велосипед, возможно такой сервис уже есть

Comment: Что понимается под "с кодом"? Что в заметках будут встречаться сниппеты (как тут в вопросах и ответах), или это должно быть два параллельных потока код|заметки?

Comment: в заметках будут встречаться сниппеты (как тут в вопросах и ответах)

Comment: Для одного пользователя или узкого/широкого круга? На чтение, на запись...

Comment: один пользователь. чтение/запись

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно какой функцонал Вы хотите получить на выходе и сколько человек будет пользоваться?! Если для внутреней сети предприятия, для парочки сисадминов, посоветую докуВики, дешево и сердито, но нужно уметь красиво форматировать текст, иначе дичь а не ресурс получится.

Сам пользовался, и встречал на предприятиях, где парк линукс серверов, в этом доку вики хранили настройки, логины пароли, топологию сети и многое другое - быстро просто удобно.

http://www.dokuwiki.ru/

Comment: Пользоваться буду один. Dokuwiki пользовался, не очень удобно. На выходе хочу получить список страниц с текстом и кодом, и вложенную навигацию по ним.

Comment: Что приходит в голову- Что-то наподобие евернот( evernote.com ).
На гитхабе полно опенсорс проектов такого плана.

Comment: не поленился воспользоваться яндексом, сразу наткнулся на nibbleblog, для Ваших задач сгодится. Подберите тему  Mydocs и пользуйтесь=) nibbleblog.com